# Convert UDX to VCF in Java

Tags: software-development, java, vcard

What libraries should I use to convert UDX file from cell-phone to [VCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard)?
`ez-vcard` doesn't work.
UDX file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<DataExchangeInfo>
    <RecordInfo>
        <VendorInfo>BRANDNAME</VendorInfo>
        <DeviceInfo>1234</DeviceInfo>
        <UdxVersion>1.0</UdxVersion>
        <UserAgent>AgentUDX</UserAgent>
        <UserInfo>UserUDX</UserInfo>
        <Encoding>UTF-8</Encoding>
        <FileSize></FileSize>
        <Language>CHS</Language>
        <RecordOfvCard>
            <vCardVersion>2.1</vCardVersion>
            <vCardRecord></vCardRecord>
            <vCardLength></vCardLength>
        </RecordOfvCard>
        <RecordOfvCalendar>
            <vCalendarVersion>1.0</vCalendarVersion>
            <vCalendarRecord></vCalendarRecord>
            <vCalendarLength></vCalendarLength>
        </RecordOfvCalendar>
        <RecordOfSMS>
            <SMSVersion>1.1</SMSVersion>
            <SMSRecord></SMSRecord>
            <SMSLength></SMSLength>
        </RecordOfSMS>
        <RecordOfMMS>
            <MMSVersion>1.2</MMSVersion>
            <MMSRecord></MMSRecord>
            <MMSLength></MMSLength>
        </RecordOfMMS>
        <RecordOfEmail>
            <EmailVersion>1.3</EmailVersion>
            <EmailRecord></EmailRecord>
            <EmailLength></EmailLength>
        </RecordOfEmail>
    </RecordInfo>
    <vCard>
        <vCardInfo>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            <vCardField>
                <N>ONE</N>
                <TELCELL>+123456</TELCELL>
                <TELHOME></TELHOME>
                <TELWORK></TELWORK>
                <TEL></TEL>
                <TELFAX></TELFAX>
                <ADRWORK></ADRWORK>
                <TITLE></TITLE>
                <ORGNAME></ORGNAME>
                <EMAIL></EMAIL>
                <GROUP_iD>4</GROUP_iD>
            </vCardField>
        </vCardInfo>
        <vCardInfo>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            <vCardField>
                <N>TWO</N>
                <TELCELL>+123456</TELCELL>
                <TELHOME></TELHOME>
                <TELWORK></TELWORK>
                <TEL></TEL>
                <TELFAX></TELFAX>
                <ADRWORK></ADRWORK>
                <TITLE></TITLE>
                <ORGNAME></ORGNAME>
                <EMAIL></EMAIL>
                <GROUP_iD>4</GROUP_iD>
            </vCardField>
        </vCardInfo>
    </vCard>
    <vCalendar>
    </vCalendar>
    <SMS>
    </SMS>
    <MMS>
    </MMS>
    <Email>
    </Email>
</DataExchangeInfo>
```

I don't know where to find a specification of the UDX format in English. [This](http://read.pudn.com/downloads116/doc/490960/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E7%A7%BB%E5%8A%A8%E7%BB%88%E7%AB%AF%E5%A4%96%E5%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E5%8F%A3%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E4%BA%A4%E6%8D%A2%20%E7%AC%AC2%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%EF%BC%9A%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E4%BA%A4%E6%8D%A2%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E6%A0%BC%E5%BC%8F%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF%E8%A6%81%E6%B1%82-%E5%BE%81%E6%B1%82%E6%84%8F%E8%A7%81%E7%A8%BF/%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E4%BA%A4%E6%8D%A2%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E6%A0%BC%E5%BC%8F-%E5%BE%81%E6%B1%82%E6%84%8F%E8%A7%81%E7%A8%BF1%5B1%5D.0.pdf) is in Chinese. I got this file from my phone which was made by KongProfit Technologies.